# How to end connectycube flutter callkit incoming call

Tags: android, ios, node.js, flutter, connectycube

I read all connectycube flutter callkit plugin documentation but i didn't find a way to end incoming call have anyone faced this issue and solved it please share the solution with us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin doesn't provide the functionality for ending a call, it provides suitable callbacks for it instead. For example, you can use the callback `onCallRejectedWhenTerminated` and HTTP method [`rejectCall(callSessionId, callMembers)`](https://developers.connectycube.com/flutter/videocalling?id=reject-a-call) for ending a call from the killed state.

Comment: please add more code and i will end this conversation